# How long does it take for S3 Lifecycle policies to get applied to the old objects in the bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

I've recently define a lifecycle policy for my s3 bucket to transition the objects to Standard IA after 30 days. The bucket contains old files (more than 30 days) and I assume those objects should change to Standard IA. But after a day those objects still show Standard (not standard IA) as their storage class. I'm wondering how long would it take for the old objects to get affected by the newly defined policy?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A rule of thumb that seems to hold is to expect the policy to take effect within 48 hours.

More specifically, you should expect to see see things happening by the time midnight UTC has occurred twice since the time you created the policy (which would be 48 hours, worst case, or slightly over 24 hours, best case) -- at the first pass of midnight, S3 starts evaluating the rules and flagging objects internally for transition, and at the second pass of midnight it actually starts transitioning the flagged objects.

The time may be longer when large numbers of objects are involved.

Review your bucket logs.  [At least some types of transitions generate log entries for each object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-and-other-bucket-config.html).

Comment: Thanks. You are right. It almost takes 48 hours to flag the objects with the new storage class.