# S3 Bucket Lifecycle Rules Not Moving Objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There is an AWS S3 bucket with a Lifecyle Rule named "Yearly Zip Archive" with the following rules:

1. Filtered scope: Applies to objects > 10MB that have the tag "LongTermZip" (just the key, no value).
2. The rule applies at Day 1 and applies to current and non-current versions (3 newest noncurrent versions are retained). Screenshot:

[image]

There is an object in the bucket that meets these criteria; it was created on 31/10/22 06:04:57 (UTC + 00:00), is 29.3 GB in size (> 10MB) and has the tag "LongTermZip". Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

From reading [this post from AWS on lifecycle rule delays](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-lifecycle-rule-delay/) my understanding is that:

1. The object was uploaded at 06:04:57 UTC 31/10/22.
2. The transition period is 1 day, giving 06:04:57 UTC 01/11/22.
3. S3 rounds the transition date up, meaning the transition date would then be 00:00:00 UTC 02/10/22.
4. However the bucket was checked at 07:57 UTC 02/11/22 and the object has still not transitioned storage class.

There is only one other lifecycle rule for this bucket; one that deletes failed multipart uploads. As such I do not think the issue is a rule conflict.

I understand from [this question and answer on time for lifecycle rules to take effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56133914/how-long-does-it-take-for-s3-lifecycle-policies-to-get-applied-to-the-old-object#:%7E:text=More%20specifically%2C%20you%20should%20expect,rules%20and%20flagging%20objects%20internally) that it can take up to 48 hours for a lifecycle rules to take effect. The lifecycle rule was made a week ago, so I don't think that is the issue.

What are possible causes of this problem?

Comment: How long has it been since the rule was created? It sometimes takes 24-48 hours for the rule to start working.

Comment: The rule was created in the afternoon of 29/10/22; so it is possible that the lifecycle rule has yet to take effect. I'll wait and see, thank you.